# ROOT_MISMATCH error after following FAQ directions

Tags: ubuntu-one, root

While using Ubuntu One in 11.04 I am unable to change my account info. When I made the switch to 11.04 I forgot that I already had an Ubuntu One account so, I made a new one. However, upon going through one of my email accounts I found my old Ubuntu One login information. I then attempted to switch the account associated with my desktop to my first email.

Now, despite following the directions found at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhatToDoWhenSyncdaemonSaysRootMismatch I continue to get the error "File sync error. (local and server roots are different (ROOT_MISMATCH))". Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before proceeding with the following please make sure that you have a backup of your local Ubuntu One folders.

Syncdaemon stores the information about server and local filesystem in ~/.local/share/ubuntuone/syncdaemon - this folder should have been removed as a part of the procedure  mentioned in the FAQ. This should also be done while syncdaemon is not running:

```
u1sdtool --quit
```

The command below should return empty result:

```
ps auxww | grep [u]buntuone-syncdaemon
```

Then please double check that you have removed your ~/.local/share/ubuntuone/syncdaemon folder completely:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.local/share/ubuntuone/syncdaemon
$ ls ~/.local/share/ubuntuone/syncdaemon
ls: cannot access /home/rtg/.local/share/ubuntuone/syncdaemon:↩
No such file or directory
```

Then you can start ubuntuone as u1sdtool --start and check whether it started with an empty metadata in ~/.cache/ubuntuone/log/syncdaemon.log.

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you very much. Now if only I could get Evolution to stop breaking when I try to go to the contacts page. lol